# Output Pin of Burleigh PZ-150 Amplifier Driver Analog High-Voltage Power Supply Unit

Tags: amplifier, analog, driver, output

I have found a Burleigh PZ-150F Analog Amplifier Driver. However, I could not locate the manual. What connector cables are compatible with the output port of this amplifier? It seems there are two male pins and two female pins.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a Lemo connector.

Comment: Peter, this is a bit thin for an answer, I must say.

Comment: Could you please let me know the spec of the Lemo connector? In the above figure, the top two are female pins and the bottom two are male pins. Thank you.

Comment: If it's a Lemo.. good luck.  Those things are expensive, and I've spent hours pouring over their catalog trying to figure out which connector I needed.  (In the end I just opened up the box and hacked a BNC into the circuit.  @ProRoc, you might do the same thing... being careful of the HV.)

Comment: It looks like the smallest 4-pin connector they make, but I haven't seen one since I retired, and even then I just used the types we had in the lab stores - never had to find a real part number or vendor.  I'd go with George Herold's suggestion to change the connector to something more readily available.

Answer (score 1):

It is a LEMO 00S 0S 1S 2S Connector FFA/ERA 2  Pin Half Moon Circular

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with the same issue. The best thing I found was here: http://physics.ucsd.edu/neurophysics/courses/physics_173_273/burleigh_PZL-PZO-PZS_piezoactuator_manual.pdf

On page 5-3, there is a part number. Hopefully that is correct. Let me know if you found a better solution.

Best,
AC